# Is it possible for Azure WebJobs sdk read preexisting blob on demand/scheduler?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Azure WebJobs sdk with BlobTrigger attribute can detect when any blob is updated or added to some container. Is it possible to write a Function that would just read existing blob on schedule or on demand with TextReader parameter, as the following:

```
ReadBlob([Blob("blah/blobname.txt")] TextReader input) {}
```

The alternative is not to use webjobs sdk and download blob with Azure Storage SDK from Main()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a scheduled/on demand job you can use `JobHost.Call`

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        JobHost host = new JobHost();
        host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("ReadBlob"));
    }

    public static void ReadBlob([Blob("blah/blobname.txt")] TextReader input)
    {
    }
}
```